# Showing entries in same category, excluding the current entry

Tags: categories, relatedto

I'm new to this, so sorry if this is really basic.

I want to display a list of entries in the same category as the main entry in my template, excluding the current entry.

This is my code:

```
{% for category in entry.tutorialCategory.all() %}
{% for tutorial in craft.entries
   .section('tutorials')
   .relatedTo(category).all()
   .id('not ' ~ entry.id) %}
       <a href="{{ tutorial.url }}">{{ tutorial.title }}</a>
{% else %}
       There are currently no related tutorials.
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I always get the 'There are currently no related tutorials.' message though.

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You might have other issues but first thing I see is the `.all()` should be at the end, not before the `.id` clause

Comment: That, was it, thanks Seb!